# Adding dotnet highcharts to Xamarin app

Tags: android, xamarin, highcharts, xamarin.android, oxyplot

I want to add `highcharts` library to my `xamarin` app. Does xamarin support it or not. I don't want to use `oxyplot` as i have already worked with highcharts in my web application

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app isn't a hybrid-app than the answer is no. The reason for this is that HighCharts are JavaScript-based charts for the web. If you want fully native charts and don't want to use oxyplot take a look at ShinobiControls.

Comment: ShinobiControls are not freeware

Comment: I know, but highcharts isn't free too, if you use it in an commercial product. So if you want a free charting library I recommend to learn how to use oxyplot as it is a powerful component.

Comment: Charts in oxyplot are not that much attractive as of in highcharts

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple. Put together an example below (Xamarin Forms), and it's not using the Highcharts .NET wrapper it's just sticking in raw javascript but you could inject it after generating it via the wrapper I'm sure. Note however you'll have to add a line for iOS to AssemblyInfo, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows

That article will also explain how to embed files (e.g. highcharts.js) in your platform-specific projects for use in WebView, which you'll have to do if you don't want to use the CDN files like I do below.

**XAML:**

```
  <Grid>
    <WebView
        x:Name="ChartView"
        Navigated="WebviewNavigated"
        Navigating="WebviewNavigating"
        Source="{Binding ChartSource}" />
  </Grid>
```

**CS:**

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
        Title = "Main Page";
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        htmlSource.Html = ChartHtml;
        ChartSource = htmlSource;
    }

    private WebViewSource _chartSource;
    public WebViewSource ChartSource
    {
        get => _chartSource;
        set => SetProperty(ref _chartSource, value);
    }

    private const string ChartHtml = @"<html>
        <body>

        <script src='https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js'></script>

        <div id='container'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            title: {
                text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of Employees'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    label: {
                        connectorAllowed: false
                    },
                    pointStart: 2010
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Installation',
                data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
            }, {
                name: 'Manufacturing',
                data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
            }, {
                name: 'Sales & Distribution',
                data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
            }, {
                name: 'Project Development',
                data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
            }],

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>";
}
```